# Should I use public methods or writeonly properties in my class?

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods, properties

I have a class library that contains a class. The class is responsible to form a connection between the program and the database and provide me with the connection string :

```
public class DBcon
{
    private string pass = "";
    private string dbName = "";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

    public string setdbName
    {
        set { dbName = value; }
    }

    public string setpass
    {
        set { pass = value; }
    }

    public OleDbConnection getsetcon
    {
        set { createcon(); }
        get { return con; }
    }

    private void createcon()
    {
        PathFinder dbPath = new PathFinder();    // just another class 

        string DBPath = "";

        dbPath.dbFilesPath = "db";
        dbPath.setDBName = dbName;
        DBPath = dbPath.dbFilesPath;

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath + ";" +
        "Persist Security Info = False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + pass + "";
    }
}
```

Firstly, I wanted to use a public method ie. createcon, to avoid all the properties but then I read that's a bad practice. 
Then I decided to use write only properties but they are also considered bad practices.

Can anyone tell me what to do to make my class a well structured class. I am using write only properties as I don't want to return strings. I just want the OledbConnection.

Any help will be appreciated even if it changes the structure of the class.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Why would you want to have writeonly properties?

Comment: so i can provide the dbName and password

Comment: _I wanted to use a public method ... but then I read that's a bad practice._ - maybe, it's not always bad. In this case I would prefer 1 method or even better a constructor. Prevents missing properties.

Comment: Why should public methods be a bad practice?

Comment: As much as it might seem rude to plow my own trumpet here, read about the Essence Pattern (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7349/The-Essence-Pattern-in-C) as your connection classes are good examples of this.  Additionally, I would make the DBName, etc properties full properties with getters, as it might be useful to retrieve the details individually (for debugging or for display to users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DBConnection
{
    private string pass = string.Empty;
    private string dbName = string.Empty;

    private OleDbConnection connection;

    public void DBConnection(string dbName, string pass)
    {
        this.dbName = dbName;
        this.pass = pass;

        this.Initialize();
    }

    public OleDbConnection Connection
    {
        get {return this.connection;}
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        //all the initialization
        var connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath + ";" +
        "Persist Security Info = False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + pass + "";
        this.connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    }
}
```

p.s. instead of using string concatenation, use [appropriate string builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) for connection path.

Comment: so having a public method is okay ?

Comment: where do you see public method? there is only the constructor.

Comment: oh sorry 
and why use string builder?
Is it more efficient ?

Comment: @WaqasAli: because this class developer specially for building syntactically correct connection strings at run-time.

Comment: Just to clarify it - the link Dmitry Martovoi provided is correct - but it's a OleDbConnectionStringBuilder, not a regular StringBuilder.